# Error: Input Runtime benchmarking wasn't enabled when building the node

Tags: benchmarking

I'm following along this benchmark [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/test/benchmark/) to run benchmarking on my Substrate node (dependencies on `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.25"`) with the command `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks` and it works successfully. But then, when I tried to run the next step with this command:

```
./target/release/my-node benchmark pallet \
--chain=dev \
--execution=wasm \
--wasm-execution=compiled \
--pallet "*" \
--extrinsic "*" \
--steps 50 \
--repeat 20 \
--output pallets/all-weight.rs
```

I got an error:

```
Error: Input("Runtime benchmarking wasn't enabled when building the node. You can enable it with `--features runtime-benchmarks`.")
```

I've checked the `runtime-benchmarks` features in Cargo.toml and `define_benchmarks!` in the Runtime but I don't think something missing there.

I suspected that the problem could probably come from `runner.sync_run` in node's `command.rs` but couldn't get a good grasp of the root cause.

What else could I miss here?

Comment: Did you change anything about the code?

Comment: If the context is Substrate node template, yes it has changed quite a lot.